# Parsing a CSV file via the download link in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, csv, google-api, cors

So I'm using the Google DFA Reporting API to extract a list of campaign report files and download the most recent one.

```
function transferData() {
    var getFile = gapi.client.dfareporting.reports.files.get({
        'profileId': '12345', // My DFA profile ID
        'reportId': reportId, // The ID of the report type
        'fileId': runId // The ID of the final report (corresponding to the report type defined earlier)
    });
    getFile.then(function (response) {
        var URL = response.result.urls.browserUrl;
        window.open(URL); // Open the download link
    }, function (reason) {
        console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
    });
}
```

This piece of code returns the URL variable, which is essentially the download link of the CSV report file, e.g. https://storage.googleapis.com/dfa_-700df587fcd884268484ea3d1/campaign_report.csv?GoogleAccessId=12345m@developer.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=12345&Signature=12345

But **now I need to parse this CSV file somehow**. What I used to do was instantly let the users re-upload the CSV file they just downloaded so I could parse it server-side via PHP. However, I'd like to avoid the download-then-upload process and automate things a bit. I tried using AJAX, but stumbled upon a CORS error, stating that the cross origin request was blocked. Using jsonp as the datatype bypassed the CORS error, but couldn't be used, since the server returned a CSV file, right?

So can I somehow automatically parse the CSV file via the download URL that the API provides me with, without requiring the user to re-upload the CSV immediately after downloading it?

Comment: Why do you get the user to download and re-upload the file - surely you should send the link of the file to the server and get the server to download the file?

Comment: what if im trying to write a plugin so no server

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

**Option 1**
Get the user to send the URL of the file back to the server, instead of downloading the file and re-uploading it. The server can then download and parse the file itself.

**Option 2**
Write your own csv parser for javascript, using something as simple as `string.split` could work for a very basic csv that you know the format of.

**Option 3**
Use a csv parsing library like [Papa Parse](http://papaparse.com/) to do the hard bit for you in the browser.

You can use the following code to implement option 2 or 3:

```
<script>

function loadDoc(url) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      parseFile(xhttp.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}

function parseFile(csvFile){
  //contents of the csv file are now in csvFile
  alert(csvFile);
}

</script>
```